# Retrofit Android возможные варианты json

Tags: android, retrofit

Имеется некоторый api запрос, в котором может быть один из параметров, а может и не быть. Как для таких Json создавать класс?
Например, возможные варианты json.

**Пример 1**

```
{
    "orders": [],
    "info": {
        "message": "Внимание! Новые тарифы на курьерскую доставку по МСК и СПБ",
        "color": "#fec831"
    },
    "success": true
}
```

**Пример 2**

```
{
    "orders": [],
    "success": true
}
```

т.е отсутвует parameter info.

Было бы просто, если бы этот параметр был, но его значения было бы Null, но тут к сожалению не так

Comment: Объявлять и использовать как-будто он есть всегда, но может быть `null`

Answer (score 2):

Вы можете создать модель в которой будут все поля, которые могут придти от сервера. Если вы знаете, что какое-то поле может не придти добавляете ему аннотацию @Nulluble и соответственно всегда проверяете на null все места где вы с ним работаете.